# Laravel 5 Elixir + gulp mix and version multiple css or less files

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have a separate css/less file for my landing / login page. How do I tell gulp, that it should compile two files for me? Here is my approach which generates unfortunately only one file for me.

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    // only for the landing-page
    mix.less('landing.less')
        .version('css/landing.css');

    // for the application, after login
    mix.less('app.less')
        .version('css/app.css');
});
```

On my landing page, I've assumed something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir("css/landing.css") }}">
```

but the build/css folder only shows my css/app.css file. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not call `mix.version()` twice:

simply do:

```
elixir(function (mix) {

    mix.less('landing.less');

    // for the application, after login
    mix.less('app.less');

    mix.version([
       'css/app.css', 
       'css/landing.css'
    ]);

});
```

This will generate two files **app.css** and **landing.css** for you in `/public/build/css`

Comment: Hmm, your example did not work for me, but you gave me the right idea!

Comment: sorry i forgot to include them in square braces mix.version(['css/app.css', 'css/landing.css']);

Comment: One problem left is that .map-files are not copied to the /public/build/ folder after using mix.version().

Comment: Thanks for this! I sort of wish the Laravel docs would have highlighted this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Digitlimit answer, I was able to solve my problem. I've inserted the files as an array and it just works :)

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.less(['landing.less', 'app.less']);
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'css/landing.css']);
});
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to  include them in square braces `mix.version(['css/app.css', 'css/landing.css']);` :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
elixir(function(mix) {
mix.styles([
    'normalize.css',
    'main.css'
], 'public/assets/css/site.css');
});
```